# Pants unable to bootstrap because Invalid Python interpreter version

Tags: python, pants

I'm trying to setup a Java project using Pants in Linux — specifically Arch Linux.

I'm following the [documentation](https://www.pantsbuild.org/v1.30/docs/installation) to just install it, but I'm always getting an error when running `./pants --version`:

```bash
$ ./pants --version 
Invalid Python interpreter version for /usr/bin/python3. For `pants_version = "2.12.0"`, Pants requires Python 3.7, 3.8, or 3.9 to run
```

I do have Python 3.9.9 installed via [asdf](https://asdf-vm.com/) and *activated* for the sub-directory in question.

```bash
$ python --version 
Python 3.9.9
```

Moreover, my configuration already have Python 3.x installed as well by default. So even if I disable the asdf version I do have it in the system:

```bash
$ python --version
Python 3.10.5
```

Is there a way to just overcome this issue? I still don't understand why the `pants` script is unable to discover the Python interpreter. I do really prefer to use the *local* version that asdf "activates" because any time the system updates it will probably update the version to one that would be incompatible at some point.

Comment: Make sure `/usr/bin/python3` is also pointing to the appropriate version of Python, as that's what the `pants` script seems to be calling.

Comment: Running `/usr/bin/python --version` or `/usr/bin/python3 --version` both yield the same result: `Python 3.10.5`. So I guess this should be fine, right? Still, `Pants` is unable in my system to use it.

Comment: Are you sure `pants` is compatible with 3.10? The error message only mentioned 3.7-3.9.

Comment: Not sure for real. I'm not very familiar with Python either, but I would expect a minor version to be compatible with the previous one, but looks like they are very specific with the version numbers in that shell script :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an option to overcome this issue in `pants.toml`:

```ini
[python-bootstrap]
search_path = ["<ASDF_LOCAL>", "<PATH>"]
```

This basically means `Pants` will first the `ASDF` interpreter with the version in `<BUILD_ROOT>/.tool-versions` and then what's in `PATH`.

> More information on this can be found [here](https://www.pantsbuild.org/docs/python-interpreter-compatibility#changing-the-interpreter-search-path).

Regardless, the setup process is *all too titchy still* and the `system` version must be set as well.

I [filed an issue](https://github.com/pantsbuild/pants/issues/16283) in the `Pants` repository and that's where I got the help from. I'm just documenting what's there here.